# How to read mutliple images in a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have segmented results in a folder. Those need to be read in a for loop and processed further in the loop. I tried reading as below:

```
for i=1:10 
file_name=dir(strcat('C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\')); 
  im=imread(strcat('C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\',file_name(i).name));
  %processing of read image
end
```

An error was thrown :??? Error using ==> imread at 370
Can't open file "C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\." for reading;
you may not have read permission.

Please suggest where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Now you have the answer, but may I criticize that you really should have figured out this solution on your own; just by taking a look at the data, which is an essential part of debugging? Maybe next time ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your problem is that:

```
file_name(1).name = .     % Stands for current directory
file_name(2).name = ..    % Stands for parent directory
file_name(3).name = your_file_name.jpg
```

Now, do:

```
images = dir('*JPG')
for i=1:numel(images) 
file_name=dir(strcat('C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\')); 
  im=imread(strcat('C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\',images(i).name));
  %processing of read image
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the R2014b release of MATLAB with the Computer Vision System Toolbox, you can do this in one line using the [imageSet](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/imageset-class.html) object.

```
images = imageSet('C:\Users\adminp\Desktop\dinosaurs\');
```

will create an object containing the paths to all the images in the `dinosaurs` directory. It will exclude any non-image files automaticaly.

Then you can process your images as follows

```
for i = 1:images.Count
  im = read(images, i);
  % process the image
end
```

Comment: Note: this must be quite new functionality as I don't have it in 2013b CVST, but +1 anyway because ooh, shiny new thing.

Comment: @nkjt, Yes, brand new. It was added in 2014b together with the support for bag-of-features object category recognition.